# Two or more models razor c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Within Razor is it possible for me to add another model, I currently have

```
@model Models.ListModel
```

I would like to add another model into the razor view e.g.

```
@model2 Model.PostModel
```

Comment: No. You need to create a view model containing properties for each model

Comment: Make a new model that contains both models. Like `class MasterModel { public class ListModel{} public class PostModel{}`. You can access each model like `MasterModel.ListModel`. `Model.ListModel`; if you are having individual process for both models on single page, then make two partial views and render them on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Create a ViewModel with both the classes inside it
Example:

```
public class PostListViewModel
{
    public List ListModel{ get; set; }
    public Post PostModel{ get; set; }
}
```